# How to include pathelement on condition in Ant

Tags: path, ant, conditional-statements

I have two jars, say `a.jar` and `b.jar`. I want to, using Ant, include either one of them as `pathelement` depending on whether a property is set/exists. If the property exists, I will include `a.jar` and `b.jar` otherwise.
However, I have my `path` declared outside of `target`. What would be the best way to do this?

Here is snipplet of my existing script. Please see what changes can be made. Thank you.

```
...
    <property name="utils.jar.name" value="a.jar" />
...
    <condition property="utils.jar.name.set" else="false">
        <isset property="utils.jar.name"/>
    </condition>
...
    <path id="master-classpath">
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}" />
<!--
    if utils.jar.name.set then
            <pathelement path="${utils.project.dist.dir}/lib/${utils.jar.name}" />
    else 
            <pathelement path="${utils.project.dist.dir}/lib/b.jar" />
-->
        <path refid="extlib-to-deploy" />
        ...
    </path>
...
    <target name="build" description="...">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.8" target="1.8" failonerror="true" debug="${compile.debug}">
            <src path="${src.dir}" />
            <classpath refid="master-classpath" />
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${build.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${res.dir}" />
        </copy>
    </target>
```